# Highcharts - Labels cut off

Tags: javascript, highcharts, data-visualization

There are a few questions on this topic but none have helped me.

I have a web app which visualises excel data in Highcharts. User uploads their data and the app visualises it.

**Problem:** The category labels are being cut off. This usually happens right after a user uploads their data, on the first view.

**Potential reason:** Could it be because we are changing the font style when the chart is being rendered? I guess the default font is Lucida? And we are changing it to courier and something odd happens?

**Note:** I cannot use fixed values for the height, width, margins. It depends on the data. Some have long labels some don't. It's dynamic.

[image]

Comment: Seems like some code and/or CSS is needed here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually an Highcharts bug and it occurs because you use a different font. Check GitHub issue: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/6782.

The workaround (which is not the perfect one) is to use axis labelGroup width to set chart left margin with some additional offset when the load event occurs:

```
events: {
  load: function() {
    var chart = this,
        xAxis = chart.xAxis[0],
        width;

    width = xAxis.labelGroup.getBBox().width;

    chart.update({
        chart: {
        margin: [50, 50, 100, width + 50]
      }
    }, true, false, false);
  }
}
```

Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/wchmiel/e1qza6mc/

Comment: This might indeed be the issue. I'll double check and get back to you! Thanks for the info.